# Is gathering statistics necessary after dropping indexes and recreating them?

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

I use Oracle SQL, and I have one question. I have a table with indexes and it's statistics are gathered. I have a procedure that drops the indexes, inserts data into the table, and after that recreates the same indexes again. Do I need to gather statistics again after this procedure, or will the indexes be recognized anyway?
For gathering statistics i use:

```
EXEC dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(''MIGBUFFER'','''||table_name||''',cascade=>TRUE);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. There is no need to **gather index statistics** immediately after **index creation**, since Oracle automatically gathers stats for indexes at creation time.

From [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5010.htm#sthref6626),

> Oracle Database now automatically collects statistics during index
>   creation and rebuild.

I think it was way back in earlier releases, when you could use **COMPUTE STATISTICS**  clause to start or stop the collection of statistics on an index. But, now this clause has been deprecated. Oracle Database now automatically collects statistics during index creation and rebuild. This clause is supported for backward compatibility and will not cause errors.